# emu8086 remove items more arithmetic mean

Tags: assembly, x86-16

**organize keyboard input**

You must specify a one-dimensional array of elements from the keyboard
This array is necessary to find the arithmetic mean
Remove items more arithmetic mean
Print the resulting array of elements (elements with no more than the arithmetic mean)

```
;srednee arifmiticheskoe
data segment
    mas dw 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
    n dw 0
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

xor ax, ax
xor si, si
mov cx, 5
@1:
add ax, mas[si]
add si, 2
inc n
loop @1
cwd
idiv n

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: Your current code calculates the mean of some fixed numbers, nothing to do with keyboard input. You don't output anything. So what is your question?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. The question is how to do it
How to modify the program

Answer (score 2):

I'll show how to output the elements that are not greater than the mean value. To output an integer you first convert the number into text.

```
 ...
 idiv n     ; -> AX=mean
 mov dx,ax  ; -> DX=mean
 mov cx,n   ; -> CX=count
 xor si,si
Show:
 mov ax, mas[si]
 add si, 2
 cmp ax,dx
 jg Skip
 pusha
 ; Insert here YourRoutineThatOutputsAnInteger
 mov dl,32
 mov ah,2
 int 21h  ;Output a space to separate numbers
 popa
Skip:
 loop Show
 mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
 int 21h
 ...
```

MyRoutineThatOutputsAnInteger

```
 mov bx,sp
 mov cx,10
next:
 xor dx,dx
 div cx
 add dl,30h
 push dx
 test ax,ax
 jnz next
print:
 pop dx
 mov ah,2
 int 21h
 cmp sp,bx
 jb print
```